# The meaning of the German words in Commandos

Tags: terminology, commandos

I played the game a lot and was always fascinated with the meaning of the German words. I know some of them already, and I would like to know the meaning of the rest.

A complete list of all German words spoken in Commandos and their meaning would be helpful.

Comment: Understanding the language good enough to know how to spell it might not be given. So the best dictionary wouldn't help.

Comment: You might try to spell those phrases in phonetics. :)

Comment: @Cristina He specifically wants the german words and phrases used in the game "Commandos". That's a fairly narrow scope, aye? Well, it actually depends on just how much German is being spoken in that game. There is a difference between translating some minor amount that is just thrown in for flavour, and being a translation service. We aren't the same people responsible for making translation patches, for example.

Comment: That's it. Meta. Give me a moment. Alright, [Meta question created](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/are-questions-about-natural-languages-appropriate-specific-example-included).

Comment: @Gunner you could try [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lang=en&lp=ende), it offers a list of orthographically similar words. Once you get the hang of it, German orthography (contrarily to grammar, I hear) is rather easy to be deduced from the pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

So according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commandos_2:_Men_of_Courage#Inaccuracies)*

> Many of the "German" and nearly all the "Japanese" phrases spoken in the game are grammatically incorrect, out of context, or simply nonsensical gibberish.

Now this is in reference to Commandos 2, but its likely pervasive throughout the series.  I'd say its unlikely that you'll be able to get what it is you want...

---

*The article in question does not have a citation, and if you look over the logs of when this line was added it was by an anonymous IP address.  I was unable to verify its accuracy.

Comment: Well lucky for you I speak German and most of the things I hear in Games like CoD is like: 'This way, here they are. Start shooting.' All your random sentences you might expect from someone looking for enemies to kill!

Comment: But the one time they say "Wait, don't shoot, let's talk this out! Have a flower!" I'll feel like a real jerk.

Comment: I'm keen on knowing the meaning of the word the soldiers say when startled - "Aicolesta!". Since I cant type the word properly, I'm unable to Google translate it.

Comment: Actually it's "Ein Verletzter!" which means "Wounded!"
But "Aicolesta" will also do :D